# C++: What is the best practice of error handling (without exceptions) while reading the file

Tags: c++, error-handling, std, fstream

Consider the following example. I open the file and read first 100 bytes.

```
std::ifstream fileRead;
fileRead.open("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> buffer(100);
fileRead.read(buffer.data(), 100);
```

Can you suggest the best practice to handle all possible errors while reading the file without using exceptions?

Comment: Yes: read your C++ book, which explains to you how to properly check for errors when reading from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know which errors you're worried about, and in particular, which errors you want to handle + continue, versus errors you want to terminate upon encountering.

For example, one error you might encounter: What if the file doesn't exist (or you don't have permissions/access to it)? This check is pretty easy:

```
std::ifstream fileRead("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
if(!fileRead) {/*File doesn't exist! What do we do?*/};
```

What if the file doesn't have 100 bytes?

```
std::ifstream fileRead("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
if(!fileRead) {/*File doesn't exist! What do we do?*/}
else {
    std::vector<char> buffer(100);
    fileRead.read(buffer.data(), 100);
    if(!fileRead) {
        std::cout << "Only " << fileRead.gcount() << " bytes could be read.\n";
    }
}
```

For only the code you've provided, those are the only errors I'd write error handling for. If there is other code associated with this example, your error handling may need to be more extensive.

Note that none of these examples made use of Exception Handling: the C++ iostreams library does [most of] its error handling without throwing exceptions.